# mongodb use removeShard to remove shard,but still on draing at all

Tags: mongodb

when I use removeShard like this:

```
db.runCommand({removeShard:"shard0001"})
```

shell show below:

```
{ 
    "msg" : "draining ongoing", 
    "state" : "ongoing", 
    "remaining" : {
        "chunks" : NumberLong(1), 
        "dbs" : NumberLong(0)
    }, 
    "note" : "you need to drop or movePrimary these databases", 
    "dbsToMove" : [

    ], 
    "ok" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

---

There is no `dbsToMove` to move but only one chunk need to remove.

but I am wait these procession for two hours for only 1 record in a collection of this chunk and seems nothing changes.

how could I remove this chunk?